# Locked out of Windows 2012 Server VM Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am running a 2012 Windows Server VM in Azure. Yesterday I was testing VPN scenarios and then decided to set the Windows Firewall settings to default. This seems to have locked me out of accessing the VM using RDP. Port 3389 must be closed. I would be grateful to hear from anyone who has experienced similar difficulties and how they resolved the situation.

Comment: If you solved your problem, you need to post an answer about it. Adding a link to the question doesn't help, as it leaves the question open. Also: This needs to go to ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you nothing more to say than complain?

Comment: I see you're brand new here, so maybe you're unfamiliar with the site. I'm helping moderate the forum, as many veteran members here do. I'm not complaining. I'm helping you out. As it stands, your question (and inappropriately-placed answer, which cannot be voted on or accepted) will be deleted, helping nobody.

Comment: Your question's edit, which included the answer, has been rolled back, as answers don't belong in questions, nor does SOLVED belong in the title.